# Azure project lost endpoints and uses default now?

Tags: azure, port, default, endpoint, wcf-endpoint

A weird thing happened to my project. I have an Azure WCF project which basically consists of the WebRole and the Azure project. Azure Project contains ServiceDefinition.csdef which in turn contains stuff like endpoint information.

I was playing around in my WebRole and manually set an endpoint there. However, my original issue, due to a stupid user error, did not require this. After I removed the endpoint devinition from web.config, my webrole still gets bound to port 6627 instead of the two endpoints described in my Azure project (80 & 8080). I can't find that port being mentioned anywhere so I'm guessing it is the default.

Here's the part of the web.config that I edited (the removed part is in comments). How do I revert back to getting the configuration from the Azure project?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<!-- services>
  <service name="MyWebRole.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyWebRole.BasicUserInformationBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="MyWebRole.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services -->
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="userInformationProcessor" type="MyWebRole.BasicUserInformationBehaviorExtensionElement, MyWebRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<bindings />
<client />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <userInformationProcessor />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

[Edit] More information on the subject! The problem is related to compute emulator no longer starting at all! I don't know why the service works then, but I guess it's running it IIS alone.

Comment: You have set up the Web Role as Startup Project. Please set the Azure Cloud Service project as StartUp project for your solution. Then try again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution as mentioned in the comment is that you have to set up the Windows Azure project as the startup project not the webrole.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! How silly of me. I don't know what suddenly changed it tho as it worked splendidly before.